# Renderscript get RGB from allocation - Android

Tags: android, renderscript

I currently read rgb pixel from an Allocation Object like this:

```
float4 elementF4TL = rsUnpackColor8888(*(uchar*)rsGetElementAt(inPixels, x-1, y-1));
uchar4 pixelCharsTL = rsPackColorTo8888(elementF4TL);
float3 pixelTL = convert_float4(pixelCharsTL).rgb;
```

And then I get the pixelTL.rgb that returns the RGB values I want.
Is there an more elegant way of doing this ?

For example, `rsUnpackColor8888` takes a `uchar4` as a parameter. If I pass a variable that is set from `rsGetElementAt_uchar4(...)` that returns a `uchar4` it breaks.

I do not 100% understand what this line means: `*(uchar*)rsGetElementAt(inPixel....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary conversion and casting. For example, you're unpacking the 8888 color representation only to pack it again in the next line.

Assuming `inPixels` is your rs_allocation object for a uchar type image, you can use the normal `rsGetElementAt_*(...)` functions. You might be able to do something like this:

`float3 pixelTL = convert_float4(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x-1, y-1)).rgb;`

This function will extract a `uchar4` vector at position (x-1, y-1) in the allocation, convert it to a `float4` and then the .rgb suffix grabs only the first 3 of those elements to make a `float3` which gets assigned to your variable.

---

And just to answer your original question about `*(uchar*)...`:

Normally, you'd use a specific type for the function call such as `rsGetElementAt_uchar4(...)`, that then returns the actual `uchar4` vector as specified.

However, if you call only the generic `rsGetElementAt(...)`, it returns a void pointer -- a `void*` -- to the first element. Thus, you must cast that pointer to the data type you need, `(uchar*)rsGetElementAt(...)` in that snippet, and then you must de-reference it to get the actual value at that pointer's location, `*(uchar*)rsGetElementAt(...)`. But yeah, lot's of back and forth for what can be accomplished much more simply as shown above.

Comment: Please make sure that if you are using (x-1) and/or (y-1), that you have already bounds checked (i.e. x > 1 and y > 1). If you don't, you will read from invalid memory and most likely crash. The same holds true for any adjustment of x. You can pass the dimensions of your Allocations/launch as global variables today.